# Find the sum of the function $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\cos{x})^n$ on $(0, \pi)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Find the sum of the function $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\cos{x})^n$ on $(0, \pi)$

We have $-1\leq\cos{x}\leq 1$. So $(\cos{x})^n \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$

Please solve this problem. Please find the sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a little note $x \in (0, \pi)$ means that you have $-1 < \cos(x) < 1$, it's important that $\cos(x)$ is neither 1 nor -1.

Now given that $-1 < \cos(x) < 1$ you have $|\cos(x)| < 1$.

Remember the geometric series formula

$$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} r^n = \frac{1}{1 - r}$$

for $|r| < 1$.

Also note that your sum starts from $n = 1$ while the general geometric sum formula starts from $n = 0$ so you need to subtract $(\cos(x))^0 = 1$ at the end

Comment: Can it be solved using the concept of series of function?

Comment: You mean with the Taylor series expansion of $(\cos(x))^n$? Theoretically it would work because the Taylor series converges uniformly but I certainly wouldn't recommend it in this case.

Answer (score 2):

For a given real number $x$ the quantity $\cos x$ is a constant.

Therefore you have a convergent geometric series defined on the interval $(0,\pi)$

The formula for geometric series gives your answer as $$\frac {\cos x}{1-\cos x}$$